# "error": "TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON"

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, api

I'm currently working on a rest API using nodejs and mongodb, I've found a problem with a request that should bring to me the information based on an id.

I keep receiving `TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON`, through many attempts and checking other questions there is no solution.

```
router.get('/store/:id', async (req, res) => {
    const { id } = req.params;
    const db = req.app.locals.database;
    try{
    const result = await db.collection(collection).find({store_id : id }).toArray();
    console.log(result);
    res.json(result);
    }
    catch (error) {
        res.status(500).json({ error: error.toString() });
    }
})
```

This is the structure of the information coming from database:

```
 {
        "_id": "5d1809974f7a7c32cb742f79",
        "timestamp": "25-03-2004 21:18",
        "store_id": 2,
        "user_id": 2,
        "product_id": "5d041fa86a8d2c001dad47ba",
        "price": 1116
    }
```

I would really appreciate any hint or help and thank you for taking the time to read my question.

Comment: What is the actual output you get from `console.log(result);`?

Comment: what package are you using? Mongoose?